# ¿Como poner mi imagen y mi form a la misma altura?

Tags: html, css

Sé que es una pregunta algo tonta xd.

Ocurre que como se puede ver en la imagen, el form, a pesar de tener el margin-top y el padding-top en 0, se ubica en la parte inferior de la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo elimino la imagen, ahora sí el form se ubicara en lo mas alto de la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Aqui esta el codigo](https://codepen.io/treZeta/full/zYdxwJp)

Comment: La forma más fácil de contarnos esta historia es incluir además, el CSS y el HTML correspondientes. :) Así será evidente el problema en tus estilos o en la construcción del HTML

Comment: La pregunta debe ser autocontenida. Que no dependa de sitios externos para que les sirva a otros en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner todo el contenedor en display flex y al contenedor del formulario lo pones width::100

al container le pones la clase general

```
<div class="container general">
```

y el formulario lo metenes en un div con id **general-form**

```
<div id="general-form">
<form action="">
```

asi seria el css

```
#general-form{
  position:relative
}
.general{
  display:flex
}
#general-form form{
      width: 100%;
}
```

completo

```
<div class="container general">
  <img
    src="https://svgshare.com/i/b3T.svg"
    alt="Hombre elegante hablando por megafono"
  />
  <div id="general-form">
    <form action="">
      <h1>Inicia Sesión</h1>
      <p>
        Accede para hacer parte del crecimiento, registro, control de los
        estudiantes.
      </p>
      <div class="slider">
        <a class="enabled" href="">Iniciar Sesión</a>
        <a class="disabled" href="">Registrarse</a>
      </div>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" /><br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" /><br />
      <input type="button" class="button" value="Ingresar" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");

  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  :root {
    --blueGem: #470e92;
    --nero: #262236;
    --inputBg: #f5f6f8;
    --inputBorderColor: #dedede;
    --lightTextColor: #272727;
  }

  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  form {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 29%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }

  img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: var(--lightTextColor);
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }

  h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: var(--lightTextColor);
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .slider {
    display: flex;
    width: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    /* justify-content: space-around; */
  }

  .slider > a {
    color: var(--blueGem);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--blueGem);
    border-width: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }

  .slider > a.enabled {
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--blueGem);
  }

  .slider > a.disabled {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999999;
  }

  input[type="email"],
  input[type="password"] {
    background: var(--inputBg);
    outline: none;
    border: 0.5px solid var(--inputBorderColor);
    padding: 13px 27px;
    font-family: inherit;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: var(--lightTextColor);
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  input:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  .button {
    background: var(--blueGem);
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: 1px solid var(--blueGem);
    margin-top: 13px;
  }
  #general-form {
    position: relative;
  }
  .general {
    display: flex;
  }
  #general-form form {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 44px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hill-mt5ce?file=/index.html:0-2785

Comment: Gracias, de hecho yo ya tenia todo organizado con flexbox pero debido a que tengo que añadir un footer (copyright) debajo de el form, le quite el flexbox. Creo que es mejor dejar el flexbox y pensar que hago con el footer 

Comment: Pues no se cual sea el problema con el footer ,con flexbox haces lo que sea pero si te sirvio es con gusto

Comment: Segun yo, el problema es que, como el flex direction es row, si pongo el footer despues de el form, se va a poner a la derecha envés de abajo y no hay manera de cambiarlo si es que permanezco en flexbox

Comment: es verdad entonces lo que haces es crear un div flex con flex-direction :column asi se van hacia abajo los  divs que metas ahi, puede ser todo el formulario y el otro el footer

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-water-fugom?file=/index.html